# Remove cells in Excel which have zero values

Tags: vba, excel

I have been trying to remove/hide cells which values are equal to zero (0).

```
Sub HideRows()
    Dim cell As Range, rng As Range
    Cells.Rows.Hidden = False

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = Columns(5).SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlNumbers)
    On Error GoTo 0

    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value = 0 Then
            cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

The code removes the entire row. I want to remove the description of the value and the value.

Comment: You can clear the contents of the cells that have 0 - but you can only hide entire rows or columns, not single cells. Do you mean you want to delete cell contents and any comments

Comment: @brettdj I want to delete the cell which has a zero value and the cell before it.

Answer (score 3):

This code will quickly clear (erase) values and comments from cells in column E that have a value of 0

```
Sub Testme()
      Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Columns(5)
With rng1
    .AutoFilter 1, "0"
    With rng1.Offset
        .ClearContents
        .ClearComments
    End With
    With rng1.Offset(0, -1)
        .ClearContents
        .ClearComments
    End With
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 Autofilter is the way to go! You might want to edit it slightly as the user want to clear this cell and the cell before it. `@brettdj I want to delete the cell which has a zero value and the cell before it`

Comment: @Sean What do you mean by `the cell before it` Horizontally or Vertically?

Comment: @brettdj Still, nothing happens.

Comment: When you say 0 do you mean 0 or empty?

Comment: @Sean: Two questions for you. Does your data have headers in Row 1? What do you mean by `delete`? Clear the cell contents or actually delete the cell? Deleting the cell will actually move cells around.

Comment: @SiddharthRout There is no header. Just to clear the cell contents.

Comment: @Sean: Then the above code given by brettdj works nicely... Are any rows hidden in your worksheet?